# What's the most common way of describing the action of putting asphalt on the road?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What's the most common way of describing the action of putting asphalt on the road?

1) The workers are laying asphalt on the road.

2) The workers are covering the road with asphalt.

3) The workers are rolling out asphalt on the road.

4) The workers are putting down a layer of asphalt on the road.

5) The workers are coating the road with asphalt.

6) The workers are covering the road with asphalt.

or what?

Comment: Why would you think there was one right way?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Why not? This action is quite common, so there should be some way to describe this action in English, which wouldn't sound weird to a native speaker.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the meaning of the phrase **one right way**.  It means "only one right way" which is what "the right way" in your question implies.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - How should I have phrased that?

Comment: Perhaps "Is any of these sentences not an idiomatic way of stating that asphalt is being put on the road?"  Or "Is there a single verb that means to put down a surface on a road?"

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Okay, I've just changed it.

Comment: All of those sentences are idiomatic ways of stating it.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Okay, I've changed it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use **["pave"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pave)** which means:

> to lay or cover with material (such as asphalt or concrete) that forms
>   a firm level surface for travel

So your sentence will be:

> The workers are paving the road with asphalt.

Comment: Yes, paving or even asphalting.

Comment: You often see the verb  " to surface" used in Britain. A new road will need to be surfaced before it can be opened to motor traffic, and an existing road may need to be resurfaced if the covering e.g. asphalt, tarmac etc becomes worn.  You see notices warning that a street or road will be closed for surfacing or resurfacing work. You know there will be trucks belonging to surfacing contractors and the smell of tar.